# How i can upload my file to DB mysql with Jquery EasyUI?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, jquery-easyui

I'm working with Jquery EasyUI and I have a trouble with this code. I have a form to input a file to DB and the form has a `input type = file` that I want to allow an attachment. However, when the form is submitted, the $_FILES object has nothing in to DB and to the path declared.

I hope that somebody can help me to solve this trouble code.
Thank you

Here is my listening code:

---

```
<form id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file_att" id="file_att" size = "30px;" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true"/>
</form>
```

---

Here is my code to run the form when the form submitted:

---

```
<?php
    include "../inc/inc.koneksi.php";

    $file_att=$_FILES["file_att"]["name"];
    $target="file_att/$file_att";
    $temp=$_FILES["file_att"]["tmp_name"];


    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO t_director(id_direc,file_att) VALUES ('NULL','$file_att')");
    if(!empty($file_att)){
        move_uploaded_file("$temp","$target");
        echo "Success Attached";
    }
    else {echo "Failed";}               
?>
```

Comment: First of all you should drop the mysql commands in favour of [mysqli or PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), since mysql is deprecated. Second, uploading a file without setting a size limit sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Show your jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you fail to upload the file for some reason. Try he following code:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $target)) {
    echo "File uploaded";
} else{
    echo "Error!";
}
```

instead of:

```
move_uploaded_file("$temp","$target");
echo "Success Attached";
```

if this outputs and error, try `var_dump($_FILES["file_att"]);` to get the error code. More info on the error codes can be found [here](https://www.php.net//manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).

Also, your file is located at `$_FILES["file_att"]["tmp_name"]` before you move it, thus you will save only it's file name inside the database, not the file itself.

Third: Like I stated inside the comments, use mysqli/PDO and, for your sanity's sake, create a file limit with

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="XXX">
```

where XXX is the value in bytes.

EDIT: Also, check your server's post_max_size and upload_max_file_size.

Comment: i was try to change the code but nothing have a solution           <?php
    include "../inc/inc.koneksi.php";

    $file_att=$_FILES["file_att"]["name"];
    $target="file_att/$file_att";
    $temp=$_FILES["file_att"]["tmp_name"];


    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO t_director(id_direc,file_att) VALUES ('NULL','$file_att')");

    if(move_uploaded_file($temp, $target)) {
     echo "File uploaded";
 }
 else{
    echo "Error!";
}              
?>

Comment: it says "File uploaded" or "Error" when you try to upload a file?

Comment: If it says error it means exactly what I said. It fails to upload the file for some reason. So what does var_dump($_FILES["file_att"]) output?

Comment: it says "NULL Error!"

Comment: NULL meants that you sent the file to the wrong php file. Can you add your jquery code inside your question?